# why calling a variable as remove()'s argument gives an error?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and I'm trying to create a class with a constructor that takes a name and creates a file "name.txt". But I want this class to have a method to remove the created file. 
 
The problem is: 
 if I use

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    remove("name.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

it works perfectly, but if I use a variable

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name = "name";
    string filename = name + ".txt";
    remove(filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio Code gives this error

[image]

in English, it's something like

```
no instance of overloaded function "remove" matches the argument list --
```

and if I run the code it returns this error

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
user.h: In member function 'void user::reset()':
user.h:72:28: error: no matching function for call to 'remove(std::__cxx11::string&)'
             remove(filename);
                            ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdio:42:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ext\string_conversions.h:43,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:5402,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\string:52,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:270:41: note: candidate: int remove(const char*)
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  int    remove (const char *);
                                         ^~~~~~
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:270:41: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\algorithm:62:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\stdc++.h:65,
                 from user.h:4,
                 from main.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:893:5: note: candidate: template<class _FIter, class _Tp> _FIter std::remove(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&)
     remove(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
     ^~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:893:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
user.h:72:28: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 1 provided
             remove(filename);
                            ^
```

What's wrong with calling a variable instead of typing a string directly as an argument?

Comment: [`remove`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) takes a `const char*`.

Comment: Look at the candidate declaration and compare the types `const char*` and `std::string`, nothing suspicious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remove` is an old-fashioned function that takes a `const char*` as an argument.

That's why it works for a string constant. (`"name.txt"` is a `const char[9]` type that *decays* to a `const char*` pointer.)

```
remove(filename.c_str());
```

will achieve this for a `std::string`.

Your ill-advised use of `using namespace std;` is bringing in all sorts of compiler diagnostics emanating from `std::remove` which does something very different.

---

These days we like to use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Remove expects an const char * object while you are sending a string one. To make it work, you should use:

```
remove(filename.c_str());
```